# How to specify the migration folder path in node-pg-migrate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-pg-migrate

I'm using the package node-pg-migrate to control my migrations, but i can't specify the folder i want to create the migration file in CLI.

When i run `node-pg-migrate create my first migration --migration-dir .\src\infra\db\config\pg\migrations\` i got an error:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\PTI\Documents\projects\ArchMaster\migrations\1678477686024_my-first-migration-.\src\infra\db\config\pg\migrations\.js'`

It's seens that "create" does'nt support specify the directory, is that rigth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your package.json update your script from `"node-pg-migrate"` to `"node-pg-migrate -m './path/to/desired/folder'"`

e.g:

```
"scripts": {
    "migrate": "node-pg-migrate -m './app/migrations'",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Was extremely frustrated with this. Why does it work? Is that because setting up a script like "migrate": "node-pg-migrate" disables CLI arguments?